# Auto full screen iframe video without using any api

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, fullscreen

Is that possible to make "auto full screen a iframe video with out using any api". i already tried youtube api its working well.but i need to know is that possible or not.any explain me with demo please. thank you.

Or any other methods / hacks to achive this solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a solution with javascript. It's working for Mozilla and Webkit browsers.

You can use `element.mozRequestFullScreen();` and `element.webkitRequestFullScreen();`

Example :

```js
function goFullscreen(id) {
    var element = document.getElementById(id);

    if (element.mozRequestFullScreen) {
      element.mozRequestFullScreen();
    } else if (element.webkitRequestFullScreen) {
      element.webkitRequestFullScreen();
   }
}
```

```html
<img class="video_player" src="image.jpg" id="player"></img>
<button onclick="goFullscreen('player'); return false">Fullscreen</button>
```

To allow fullscreen mode for an `<iframe>` elements, you need to set your iframe on `allowFullScreen` :

```
<iframe src="iframe.html" width="100" height="100" allowFullScreen></iframe>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Html5 feature, using video tag

```
<video width="321" height="244" controls>
<source src="folder/movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
<source src="folder/movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

Or You may use iframe.

```
<iframe src="folder/movie.mp4" width="550" height="380"
frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen>
</iframe>
```